# What is the meaning of this code "var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);"?

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, require

I am interested to know how does the following line of the code work?

`var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);`

I mean what is the meaning of the second prantheses `(session)`? How does this syntax work?

Comment: The second pair of parenthesis calls a function.

Comment: It means that the `session-file-store` module exports a function, which is then called immediately with the `session` parameter

Comment: @tkausl: So it is a more specified import command.